# Calculation of S3’s byte-hour

Tags: amazon-s3

S3 uses the concept of Byte-Hour in billing: https://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/#Billing

Unfortunately (in typical Amazon AWS style) they left some details unsaid, namely what happens in the case of partial Byte-Hours.

So here is my question in the form of an example:

Suppose I store 1TB of data at Key A in my bucket.
After half an hour, I delete Key A and store 1TB of data in Key B of the bucket.
After just prior to half an hour more, I delete Key B.

In this example, will I be charged for 1TB-hour (2x 1TBx0.5hrs), or for 2TB-hours (1TB-hour + 1TB-hour).

Please assume this is a rational and worthwhile question to ask, and not query me for my motivations, life aims etc. Thanks :}

Comment: I would expect it to be rounded up to a whole hour, but it is just a guess.